# Qrcode problems

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i am having problems with thr qrcode scaner in my. I want to fetch data from my firebase forestore using value gotten from my qrcode scanner. the problem is that when i scan the qrcode, nothing displays. perhaps I am making an error. Help would be appreciated. here is the code. Ps the value of the qrcode I am scanning is definitely in the firestore so that cannot be the problem

```
class Scan extends StatefulWidget {
  const Scan({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Scan> createState() => _ScanState();
}

class _ScanState extends State<Scan> {
  String _scanBarcode = 'Unknown';
  Future<void> startBarcodeScanStream() async {
    FlutterBarcodeScanner.getBarcodeStreamReceiver(
        '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.BARCODE)!
        .listen((barcode) => print(barcode));
  }

  Future<void> scanQR() async {
    String barcodeScanRes;
    try {
      barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
          '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.QR);
      print(barcodeScanRes);
    } on PlatformException {
      barcodeScanRes = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }
    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _scanBarcode = barcodeScanRes;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Stream<QuerySnapshot> vehicleStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('vehicle info').where('qrcode', isEqualTo: _scanBarcode).snapshots();
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: TextButton(
            onPressed: (){
              scanQR();
            },
            child: Text('Tap to scan QRcode',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                color: Colors.grey.shade600
              ),
            )
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: vehicleStream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Something went wrong');
          }
          if(!snapshot.hasData){
            return Center(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    scanQR();
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 40,
                      width: 120,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                        color: const Color(0xff7F78D8).withOpacity(0.5),
                      ),
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text('Tap to scan item',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              fontSize: 14
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
            );
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Text("Loading");
          }

          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
              final vehiData = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Text(vehiData['color']),
                  Text(_scanBarcode)
                ],
              );
              }
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you do some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected? If so, what was the results?